# Symfony2.6 - Service

Tags: symfony

I have learnt Symfony2 since several months.

I have created a service. When I use it in a simple controller, I have no problem. When I use it in my controller that manages my entity, I have a problem.

My service is:

```
<?php
namespace Cours\BlogBundle\Services;
class Service1
{
    public function creerSlug($texte)
    {        
        $texte = transliterator_transliterate("Latin-ASCII; [:Punctuation:] Remove; Lower();", $texte);
        $texte = preg_replace('/[-\s]+/', '-', $texte);
        $texte = trim($texte, '-');
        return $texte;
    }
}
```

My simple controller is:

```
<?php
namespace Cours\BlogBundle\Controller;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Cours\BlogBundle\Services\Service1;
class TestController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $texte = "Le test du slug";
        $service1 = $this->container->get('service1');
        $texte = $service1->creerSlug($texte);
        return $this->render('CoursBlogBundle:Test:index.html.twig', array('texte' => $texte));
    }
}
```

The action of my controller that manages my entity is:

```
public function ajouterAction(Request $request)
{
    $rubrique = new Rubrique();
    $form = $this->createForm(new RubriqueType(), $rubrique);        
    if ($request->isMethod('POST'))
    {
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if ($form->isValid())
        {
            $manager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $rubrique = $form->getData();
            $texte = $rubrique->getTexte();
            $service1 = $this->container->get('service1');
            $slug = $serviceSlug->creerSlug($texte);
            $slug = $rubrique->setSlug($slug);
            $manager->persist($rubrique);
            $manager->flush();
            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('cours_blog_accueil'));
        }
    }
    return $this->render('CoursBlogBundle:Rubrique:ajouter.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView()));
}
```

My view tells me that my slug can’t be empty.

I think there is a mistake in my action but I can’t find it.

Does anyone help me?

KISSES AND THANK YOU VERY MUCH

Comment: var_dump the slug and see if the returned value from creerSlug function is actually not empty. if it is empty which would be most likely the case then you have your culprit , test your function

Comment: Is `$rubrique->getTexte();` returning value?

Comment: This is a simple debug question. I don't know what `transliterator_transliterate` does. Why don't you write a test? `$this->assertThat($service->creerSlug("-abc-def ghi -- jkl   "), $this->equalTo("abc-def-ghi-jkl"));` ? You could use PHPUnit's provider technique to check many inputs and expected outputs.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
    $service1 = $this->container->get('service1');
    $slug = $serviceSlug->creerSlug($texte);
```

to

```
    $serviceSlug = $this->container->get('service1');
    $slug = $serviceSlug->creerSlug($texte);
```

Comment: Hello,

I thank you for your answers.

I did a copy/paste mistake when I created this topic.

$service1 = $this->container->get('service1');
$slug = $service1->creerSlug($texte);

Comment: The slug is not completed in the form. So, $slug = $rubrique->setSlug($slug); fills the property slug.

I used @Assert\NotBlank() in my entity for slug and I don't use slug when I completed the form.

I don't know how I can put this topic in resolved topic.

KISSES

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to comment/remove `$rubrique = $form->getData(); $texte = $rubrique->getTexte();` from `ajouterAction` and set the text manually (just for testing purpose):

```
if ($form->isValid())
{
    $manager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    // $rubrique = $form->getData();
    // $texte = $rubrique->getTexte();

    $rubrique->setTexte('Some text');

    $service1 = $this->get('service1');

    $slug = $service1->creerSlug($rubrique->getTexte());
    ...
```

if it works, you can set some validations to the `texte` field in your form type which prevents entering an invalid value.

Also I suggest to use some libraries ([Cocur/Slugify](https://github.com/cocur/slugify) can be a good option) instead of handling the process by yourself.